# Serializing a Drawable object on Android

Tags: android, serialization, drawable

I'm trying to speed up my ListView by cacheing the images and loading them from the phone rather than the internet when scrolling the list. However, I run into an exception when I try to serialize the Drawable object. This is my function:

```
    private void cacheImage(Drawable dr, Article a){
    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = openFileOutput(a.getArticleId().toString(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(dr); 
        oos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This nifty bit of code results in:

**java.io.NotSerializableException: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable**

What is the best approach to serialize these images?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should only need to cache bitmap (drawables) that you i.e. fetched from the internet. All other drawables are most likely in your apk.

If you want to write a Bitmap to file you can use the `Bitmap` class:

```
private void cacheImage(BitmapDrawable dr, Article a){
    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = openFileOutput(a.getArticleId().toString(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        dr.getBitmap().compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to work, but how would I go about reading the stored images back into my application?

Answer (score 0):

In case your `Drawables` are all `Bitmaps` you can store them using [Bitmap.compress()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress%28android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream%29)

Answer (score -2):

Please see http://code.google.com/p/shelves/ Google Shleves project they are actually doing what you want. please see code they are maintaining WeakReference and SoftReference to Images.