# How to serialize a class that has Drawable as property?

Tags: android, serialization

So I have this class

```
public class PaymentsAddVm {

    private Drawable drawable;

    public Drawable getDrawable() {
            return drawable;
    }  

    public void setDrawable(Drawable resourceId) {
         this.drawable = resourceId;
    }
}
```

I need to be able to pass it to Intent but it require serializable object. Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve by passing this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692492/serializing-a-drawable-object-on-android

Comment: please check this link. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4880953/5343866

Comment: I think you can write to a file then pass file path to another component.

Comment: Convert Drawable object to byte array. Then pass that array to intent. In Activity B, you receive intent with byte array and create drawable again.